# django function based generic views migration to class based views

Tags: django, django-views

i recently migrated from django 1.4 to django 1.5 and i am getting this error

```
ViewDoesNotExist: Could not import django.views.generic.date_based.archive_index. Parent module django.views.generic.date_based does not exist.
```

googling gives me that function based views have been deprecieted. I am trying to migrate to Class based views but is finding it difficult. here is my views.py

```
from app.models import Season
from django.conf.urls import *
from cms.models import News, File


def get_extra_context():
    past_seasons = Season.objects.filter(in_progress = False)
    try:
        current_season = Season.objects.get(in_progress = True)
    except Season.DoesNotExist:
        current_season = None
    files = File.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:5]
    output = {
        'current_season': current_season,
        'past_seasons': past_seasons,
        'files': files,
        }
    return output

dictionary = {
    'queryset': News.objects.all(),
    'date_field': 'date',
    'extra_context': get_extra_context(),
}


urlpatterns= patterns(
    'django.views.generic.date_based',
    url(
        r'(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
        'object_detail',
        dict(dictionary, slug_field = 'slug', template_name = 'cms/news/object.html'),
        name='object'
    ),
    url(
        r'^$',
        'archive_index',
        dict(dictionary, template_name = 'cms/news/list.html'),
        name='list'
    )
)
```

i am not able to convert it class based views. can any body help. dictionary is the object i want to put into the context.

thanks in advance.

//mouse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how i did it.

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(
        r'(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
        DateDetailView.as_view(
            model = News,
            date_field = 'date',
            slug_field = 'slug',
            template_name = 'cms/news/object.html',
            #dict = dictionary,
        ),
        name='object'
    ),
)
```